# When can I use "on" and "in" before countries?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

Here is an example. Has the sentence used correct preposition?

Or can I change "on" to "in"?

> The Nationalists’ coercive apparatus ***on*** Taiwan was also exclusive.

It will be more helpful if anyone provide answer with relevent example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on the word(s) found **before** the preposition.

For example, *apparatus* is often something you can use *on* something else (in this case, it could be a nation's people, or that nation's culture or  political climate, which can be represented by the name of the country).

So, to think of places where *on* would be appropriate before the name of a country, think of phrasal verbs that use *on*, or nouns that often use *on*.

That's how I managed to come up with these news quotes:

- Why is a failed policy being pushed on Greece?
- The *Economist* features a largely sanguine report on Mexico.
- In its country profile on Chile this year, Lloyd’s of London wrote...

I think it's easier to find instances where the country's name is written in possessive form:

- Investors should be focused on Brazil's efforts to curb inflation.
- Analysts have expressed concern over the impact the wildfire will have on Canada's economy.
- What impact would this have on Egypt's tourism sector?

Comment: What should I use here?

Comment: Are you sure the sentence in question belongs to this category? Doesn't it mean that the apparatus was inside the country and not something external to it? In other words: The Nationalists’ apparatus was the only power in Taiwan who might have used force.

Comment: @ixSci - No, I'm not sure at all, because there's not enough context to tell. I find _coercive apparatus_ to be a pretty vague term; it could refer to something physical, or it could be used similar to the way we talk about a "political machine," which isn't really a _machine_ like an engine, but a group of people dedicated to meeting some political goal or objective.

Answer (score 0):

As English learner, I would say that `in` must be used here. I may mistake but you should say `in some country` but you may say `on some country's territory/policy'. For instance, "[apparatus in soviet](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22apparatus%20in%20soviet%22)" gives 22 google matches whereas "[apparatus on soviet](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22apparatus%20on%20soviet%22)" gives only 3

> process of centralization of the political apparatus **on** Soviet **territory**
>
> The Impact of the Shevardnadze-Dobrynin Apparatus **on** Soviet Foreign **Policy**

As J.R. reminds to us, when some country power is used within the same country, you say "in country". You say "on Taiwan", when some global power treats Taiwan as an object. So, both in and on could be acceptable. However, "apparatus on Taiwan" is not, IMO. The apparatus was imposed **upon Taiwan**, but, it was acting **within Taiwan**. There is a verb, like *imposed* is missing to say *on Taiwan*. Since the verb is missing, we imply that apparatus was acting or existing. It was not acting upon Taiwan. It was acting in Taiwan. Therefore, on Taiwan sounds wrong there, in my uneducated opinion.

Comment: I think because Taiwan is an island both forms are appropriate.

Comment: @ixSci J.R. has explained that this has nothing to do with the island. You can treat the whole country as object and impose anything on it.

Comment: @ixSci Moreover, I think that the rule "use on the islands" is incorrect since I see 23 million matches for "in Cuba".

Comment: Well, it might be incorrect to talk about a country and use "on" like "on Cuba" but I think it is correct to use "on Cuba" when you are talking about the island. So given the sentence from the question it might talk about the island and the country is just inferred from it since there is no other country on this island. Note, however that I'm not a native speaker nor I have any particular knowledge in this question — I'm just guessing. For example, in Russian it is also incorrect to say "on Cuba" meaning the country but people say that everytime maybe this case is similar.

Comment: The sentence itself is not clear and it's not easy to know which is better without further context. You should not use the definite article before Taiwan.